# MySQL DELETE with JOIN getting syntax error with LIMIT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb, sql-delete

I am running a query to remove duplicate entries.  It works without the LIMIT statement, but overloads the server.  I'd like to batch process it using the LIMIT statement.

```
DELETE t1
FROM data as t1
join data as t2
WHERE t1.type = t2.type
AND t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp
LIMIT 100
```

And with the LIMIT statement receive the error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 100' at line 6

Answer (score 2):

you can't use direcly the limit in delete you could use in select

```
  DELETE data 
  FROM data as t1
  join (
        select distinct type, timestamp from data limit 100  
  ) t2  on t1.type = t2.type AND t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp
```

Comment: That doesn't quite do the same behavior.  In mine, if the limit worked, it would be 100 found duplicates.  This version would require a lot of backend support to process all the records correctly while handling deleted records.

Comment: if you don't need  duplicate .. use distinct  .. in subselect ... answer  updated .. so you delete 100 not duplicated  ..  values

Answer (score 1):

Multi-table `DELETE` and `UPDATE` do not permit a `LIMIT` clause.  This is the cause of the error message.  To workaround...

To do massive `DELETEs` (or `UPDATEs`), loop through the table in chunks.  [*This*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) discusses the details.  For efficiency, it uses the `PRIMARY KEY` so that walking through the table is efficient.